# Custom query for post grip

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I am using Visual Composer in WordPress in that i need to display the past events  comparing with current date.I have tried this.

```
$today = date('yymmdd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_short_order',
            'value' => date("yymmdd"),
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
```

Any one help me.

Comment: `post_type=event&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=3&meta_key=date_short_order&meta_value<$today&orderby=meta_value_num&type=DATE&order=desc` this i have tried

Comment: i need custom query for post gird

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this?

```
$today = date('yymmdd');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_short_order',
            'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
```

I replace this `'value' => date("yymmdd"),` to `'value' => date("Y-m-d"),`

Comment: Thank you.But i did not get the answer

Comment: I need custom query string for using post grid custom query.

Comment: post_type=event&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=3&meta_ke‌​y=date_short_order&m‌​eta_value<$today&ord‌​erby=meta_value_num&‌​type=DATE&order=desc this i have tried

Comment: tried like `$today = date('yymmdd');` to `$today = date("Y-m-d");`?